# Rename File on Download

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, download, rename

I'm using SharePoint Online and I'd like to know if it's possible to append a metadata column value to a filename when a user clicks "Download". The filename in SP must stay the same, but the locally downloaded version must be appended.

Comment: I also have the exact same requirement. Were you able to find a solution for this, if so can please share or give me guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out-of-the-box. But one solution could be to customize SharePoint with your own download link at the appropriate location. Use the HTML download attribute on an anchor tag. For example:

```
<a href="{SPURL}" download="{DownloadFilename}">download</a>
```

However, it will not work in all browsers. It works with Google Chrome and FireFox whereas Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge will ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work with the standard download link on libraries will it? I need a solution that works for all links without me having to edit the html each time. Plus, I don't know the filename - so a hard-coded approach won't suffice.

Comment: No, the standard download will use the filename only! You'll have to develop a custom solution. Maybe by registering some JavaScript code (through a CustomAction) that replaces the standard download link! The metadata to add can be retrieved from the web page if available or by a call back to SharePoint with the JSOM.